# target the last child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jquery questionnaire, when the user clicks on the radio button it navigates to the next question [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/y725p/). On the last question a submit button is visible, however if you click on the the last radio button all content disappears. Is there a way to deactivate the `next()` function when the user gets to the last question.

```
            $('.responsible-gaming__body input').click(function () {
            selfAssessmentTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
            var parentContainer = $(this).parents('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer');
            parentContainer.hide();
            parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').length` to see the next element existance. If it is then execute the next click code else do nothing:

```
if(parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').length){
   //next element exist....add code here
}
```

**complete code:**

```
$('.responsible-gaming__body input').click(function () {
        selfAssessmentTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
        var parentContainer = $(this).parents('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer');
        if(parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').length){
           parentContainer.hide();
           parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
        }
 });
```

Comment: This solution works, but requires two lookups for the same element, my answer only requires one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').length){
//do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').length){
       parentContainer.hide();
       parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y725p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector for click function to

```
$('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer:not(:last-child) input')
```

instead of

```
$('.responsible-gaming__body input')
```

This makes your code become simpler to:

```
$('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer:not(:last-child) input').click(function () {
  selfAssessmentTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
  $(this).parent().parent().next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only hide the parentContainer once the next container is shown (this won't happen if there isn't a next container):

```
$('.responsible-gaming__body input').click(function () {
    selfAssessmentTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
    var parentContainer = $(this).parents('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer');
    parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show(0, function() {
        parentContainer.hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y725p/3/)